# What happened to the rest of the animals created with Rocket Raccoon?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

This question stems directly from this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20853/20393).

If Rocket is only one of many animals created by the robots mentioned in the answer above, do we know what happened to the rest?

Presumably if Rocket is as tough / insane as he is, the rest could be the same.

Comment: He's not insane ... just a little nuts ;-) You'd be a little nuts, too, if you had all those implants in you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 616 continuity (the comics), Rocket and other small animals were granted humanoid abilities & intelligence so that they could act as "companions" (think seeing-eye dog) for mental patients on Halfworld. Rocket eventually ended up in a role much like that of the head guard at the asylum, but through later events found a way to cure all of the patients at the asylum.

After the patients were cured, most of the animal companions left the planet to have their own adventures, but only Rocket's adventures were shown in the comics.

Comment: Is there a Guardians of the Galaxy manga with Rocket Tanuki?

Answer (score 3):

### Indeed...

This question was tagged for the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU) and *Guardians of the Galaxy 3* makes Rocket's origin story central. Therefore *spoilers follow...*

> Rocket is a raccoon [genetically modified by the High Evolutionary, as part of a group known as *Batch 89*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Rocket_Raccoon#Genetic_Experiment). In captivity he befriended three of his cohort but all three were killed when Rocket made an escape bid. However, Rocket would eventually join the *Guardians of the Galaxy* and [return to defeat the High Evolutionary](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Rocket_Raccoon#Fighting_High_Evolutionary), and free the surviving members of *Batch 89* along with many other creations and captives of the High Evolutionary. These now [reside at *Knowhere*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Rocket_Raccoon#Guardians_Disassembled).